# In AWS Java SDK, can I run more than one handler in a single package?

Tags: lambda

[image]

I tried to create multiple handler in a single package. But when I tried to run on AWS through Eclipse, I can only add one handler to one function. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: how did you solve it? Did you use the aws toolkit for eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Upload your code artifacts to s3, then go to aws lambda console create multiple lambda functions with the uploaded artifacts from s3, providing different handlers for different functions, As shown in the picture.

Handlers like

```
Javalambda.example.GetPriceHandler
Javalambda.example.LambdaFunctionHandler
Javalambda.example.SampleHandler
```

[image]