# How to organize a Java Lambda Handler project

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, project-structure

I recently started working on AWS Lambda using Java and I need to understand how to properly structure a project like this.

Should I only create a single project for all the lambda functions, or should I create a project for each ?

I am currently following the former, and have created 10 lambda functions in one project.

I have avoided the use of Spring Boot and Spring for quicker cold start, less dependencies and smaller memory footprint, but the .jar size is already 20 MB.

Am I following a normal pattern, or how can I improve my project structure (see image) ?

[image]

Explanation: I have put all handlers in a single project and of course AWS will point to different handlers for each function.

I also want to ask, is it good design to keep them together or should I have different projects/modules for each lambda. For instance: deleteUser, disableUser etc.

Please guide me to start.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One project for all Lambda functions should be fine as, finally the Lambda Function will need to be configured to its respective Handler. Check this similar stackoverflow thread.

[Is it feasible to create multiple Lambda functions (Java) in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208841/is-it-feasible-to-create-multiple-lambda-functions-java-in-a-jar)

For Application Memory footprint, try to deploy the Lambda application and check the cold start times and memory footprint as, these 2 will determine your Lambda costs to an extent.

Frameworks like spring-boot tend to cause longer startup times.Other alternatives you could consider.

1. If your application logic is simple enough,avoid using any framework and just use core java.
2. **Spring Cloud Function**- You could consider this as a spring boot version for developing serverles applications(Ofcourse there is a lot more to it)

   https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function
3. Try **Quarks** as, they claim to have far lesser memory footprint and application startup times.

   https://quarkus.io/